# rownum notworking with subquery on oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a long query with multiple joins,

```
Select * 
  from (Select firstName, lastname, designation 
          from NameTable nameT 
          left outer join ProfileTable profileT on nameT.id = profileT.id
          where firstName like ("S%") order by firstName ASC
       ) 
  where rownum < 25
```

The above query works fine, If i change the name search to "sa" then query executing get hanging.

If i change the rownum to 21 "sa" query also gets fast.

Whether we need to add any index to table, or any idea for this question.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: Long query? This query is quite short! Do you mean long-running? Do you have any indexes on any of these tables? In particular on NameTable.firstName?

Comment: How many results are there for the `sa` query, vs the `S` query? Also, your query seems to be incomplete - I'd expect a `join` to have an `on` clause.

Comment: sa - results to 10000 recors and "s" results to 15000 records.

Comment: Long query insense, for sample I gave two table joins. But query having 5 joins with 6 tables.

Comment: We have no idea how complex your query is! When you look at the output of 'explain plan' does it look correct or plausible to you? Are you sure you have the right indexes in place?

Answer (score 0):

why you want to go for subquery here,I think it will help you

```
  Select firstName, lastname, designation 
   from NameTable nameT left outer join ProfileTable profileT 
   on nameT.column=profileT.column    
  where firstName like ("S%") and rownum < 25
```

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov in question itself its not mentioned

Comment: If the OP wants to add an `order by` to the subquery then the subquery will be needed.

Comment: In all likelihood, they are using a subquery because they want to page a *sorted* result set. The sorting is applied in the subquery and the first 24 rows are retrieved in the outer query.